# Delete images from a folder

Tags: php, delete-file

I want to to destroy all images within a folder with PHP how can I do this?

Comment: No, please, don't destroy them.

Comment: which of the 3674 other questions about http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delete+images+in+a+folder+[php] have you checked and why didnt they answer your question?

Answer (score 29):

```
foreach(glob('/www/images/*.*') as $file)
    if(is_file($file))
        @unlink($file);
```

`glob()` returns a list of file matching a wildcard pattern.

`unlink()` deletes the given file name (and returns if it was successful or not).

The `@` before PHP function names forces PHP to suppress function errors.

The wildcard depends on what you want to delete. `*.*` is for all files, while `*.jpg` is for jpg files. Note that `glob` also returns directories, so If you have a directory named `images.jpg`, it will return it as well, thus causing `unlink` to fail since it deletes files only.

`is_file()` ensures you only attempt to delete files.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest (non-recursive) way is using [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob):

```
$files = glob('folder/*.jpg');
foreach($files as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$images = glob("images/*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image){
     @unlink($image);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `unlink and glob function`

for more see this link
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php
and
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php