# Delete files using wildcard - exec vs unlink

Tags: php, exec, unlink

I'm working on a php script, where I want to delete some files from a given folder using wildcard (*).
I've found some working examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535202/delete-images-from-a-folder-php#answer-5535221), where `unlink()` and `glob()` function are used.

Now, i was wondering, would it also be ok to delete the files using the `exec` function and a command like `rm -f /path/to/folder/_prefix_*` ?
Are there any security risks taken using this?
And if it is ok, would it be better in terms of performance?

EDIT:
So, from the first answers i can see that indeed, using `exec` could be an acceptable solution.
What about performance issues? Is there any chance the `exec` option could be better (faster/less demanding) over the `glob/unlink` technique?

Thank you in advance

Comment: rm would be fine, security issues depends on who can run the script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because there is no chance for user-supplied data to be injected, there is no security issue in using `exec` over `glob/unlink`. However, using `glob/unlink` allows you to define exceptions:

```
foreach(glob("delete/*") as $f) {
    if( $f == "delete/notme.txt") continue;
    unlink($f);
}
```

And `exec` is often disabled on shared servers so `glob/unlink` is more portable. If you have a dedicated setup and don't intend on giving it up, you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks for replying Kolink. I'm on an owned server, and exec is enabled and working fine. Do you think it could make difference in performance using one technique over the other?

Comment: I would imagine `exec` is faster, but `glob/unlink` lets the script know at all times exactly what is going on - useful for console applications more than web-based, but you can also get an error report for each file, or list the deleted files...

Answer (score 2):

Both options could be fine. However, if you not control your own server or are on shared hosting, the exec command could not be available.

To be on the save side, use glob and unlink.