# laravel - delete multiple photos with unlink path wont work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

What I am trying to achieve is to delete multiple photos from one delete command, but it only delete the record from the database, but unable to delete the file in my local storage. I am trying to use unlink() method in order to make this to work. I hope somebody would enlighten me where that I made my mistake. Thank you!

**Delete method**

```
//There are 8 columns of image, the database record is wiped, but not in the local storage.

public function destroy(Gallery $gallery){

        for ($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
            $path = storage_path('app/public/' . $gallery->image_ . $i);
            
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                @unlink($path);                
            }
        }

    $gallery->delete();

}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing YOLO operator (`@`) obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: Noted, sir. I will opt to something such as File::delete to execute the same function. @tadman

Comment: I assume you are trying to use the property named `image_1`, `image_2`, etc on `$gallery`?

Comment: That function is fine, it's just the `@` that's problematic.

Comment: Instead of randomly guessing what files exist and assuming that there will be 1...8 of them, why not use [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to find out what's actually there? Like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254391/delete-files-using-wildcard-exec-vs-unlink).

Comment: Yep, it's meant to be like that, sir. @lagbox

Comment: Aaah understood. I'll give it a try on glob(). Thank you for the suggestion. @tadman

Comment: then you need to do something like this  `$gallery->{"image_$i"}` so it knows the property is `'image_1'` etc

Comment: That sorts it out! Thank you very much @lagbox