# delete image after uploading in folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete image from folder after uploading .

I am first uploading resize image in folder and by using resize image I am cropping image and saving in other folder.

So after crop I want to delete image from resize folder

Comment: please post some code, or your answer would most probably be deleted as too broad and unspecified

Comment: refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php). Hope it helps!!!

Comment: can you paste some code what have you tried till now. that will be great help to help you.

Comment: Check this from previous entries - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535202/delete-images-from-a-folder-php

Answer (score 2):

use `unlink()`. this function delete image.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) is the official documentation page

Answer (score 1):

Simple use unlink('your image physical path/image name');

Answer (score 0):

You can use unlink to delet the image.

```
$file = "images/*.jpg"
unlink($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `unlink()`. this function delete image.

Answer (score 0):

$myFile = "testFile.txt";
unlink($myFile);